# Link microsoft excel cell values with ms word fields

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

i have a question about linking ms excel cell values that are calculated from some formulas to ms word into some prices.
The excel values are currency : 77€ , 80€ etc
So i want to read the currency value from an excel cell and the link it to a ms word text box or something like this.

It look something like this.

[The table with pictures from some intercom monitors and random prices that i want to link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzucL.png)

But when i try to special paste with link & merge or link & keep source formatting i get something like this

[When i try to special paste](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I1Pt.png)

It doesn't keep my ms word formatting , only text.
I use ms word and excel 2016.

How can i do this guys , i want all these values ( prices below intercom monitors , red with blue glow around ) to update as excel cell values change.

Thank you for your time , i hope you understand what i am trying to do.

Comment: is the link you want Excel to Word ? and if it is what does the data look like when in Excel ? add these points to the question not comments, click edit question to add bits

Comment: We provide the ability to add images to posts so you can include illustrations. What are your images supposed to be ***illustrating**?* You say you want to link Excel cell values with Word fields. It looks (from your images) like you have done that. What’s the problem? What is your question? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Hi @j_pentester did U every tried Paste Special,, then Paste as Excel Object ?